# HTML5 form placeholder not appearing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I have a form which placeholder text doesn't appear for IE. I know this is a common problem as I've seen fixes everywhere online but I still can't get mine to work. I think it's because my input area already has a class (I got this form styling from somewhere else).

Below is my form in the html page:

```
<form method="post" action="send_form_email_small.php" id="">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*" /></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="tel" placeholder="Phone Number*" /></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="suburb" placeholder="Suburb/Town" /></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="How may we assist you?*"></textarea>
        </div>
        <section id="buttons">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="7" value="Submit"></input>
        <br style="clear:both;">
        </section>

    </form>
```

And below is the css for the form textarea

```
        form input.text,
        form select,
        form textarea
        {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            border: 0;
            background: rgba(250,250,250,0.8);
            width: 140px;
            margin: 6px 0px;
            padding: 10px 16px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
            -webkit-appearance: none;               
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #555;
            outline: none;
        }
```

I've done this tutorial exactly (http://webdev-il.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/how-to-make-form-placeholder-text.html) and many others and am still not sure why the text still isn't appearing in IE, so am convinced that the problem is stemming from the class="text" already in the code. I'm not a web whiz so would appreciate any help possible thank you!

Comment: The `palceholder` attribute is not a `label` and shold not be used as a replacement for it: http://www.webaxe.org/placeholder-attribute-is-not-a-label/

Comment: Another tip, you don't need `</input>` if you are self closing the opening input tag. E.g. :`<input id="thisID" class="aClass" />`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment IE doesn't have any support for placeholder text.

Have a look at this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/using-placeholder-text-in-html5-forms-across-all-browsers/1353/

Comment: This is absolutely not true. I use placeholder all the time. It has been supported for a while. http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: @ChrisLove More people use IE9 than IE10 and 11 combined. This is why  you should accommodate for those that still use it.